# Why does dynamic resizing not work if Layout is connected to the parent?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

My code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        widget_1 = QWidget()
        lay.addWidget(widget_1)

        lay_2 = QVBoxLayout(widget_1)
        label_1 = QLabel(widget_1)
        label_1.setText("Test - 1")
        label_1.setStyleSheet('background:{};margin:100'.format('yellow'))
        lay_2.addWidget(label_1)

        self.radio = QRadioButton()
        self.radio.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.radio.setStyleSheet('background:{};margin:100'.format('black'))
        lay_2.addWidget(self.radio)

        #face_widget = QWidget(self)
        #face_widget.resize(widget_1.sizeHint().width(), widget_1.sizeHint().height())
        #widget_2 = QWidget(face_widget)

        widget_2 = QWidget(self)
        widget_2.setStyleSheet('background:{}'.format('brown'))
        widget_2.move(10,10)
        #widget_2.resize(65, 55)

        widget_2.raise_()

        lay_3 = QVBoxLayout(widget_2)

        lay_3.setSpacing(0)
        lay_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        label_2 = QLabel(widget_2)
        label_2.setText("Test - 2")
        label_2.setStyleSheet('background:{}'.format('blue'))
        lay_3.addWidget(label_2)

        label_3 = QLabel(widget_2)
        label_3.setText("Test - 3")
        label_3.setStyleSheet('background:{}; padding:10'.format('red'))
        lay_3.addWidget(label_3)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is the widget_2 does not want to dynamically change its size when the Layout is connected to the parent.

I do not know what this is connected with. And I don’t know how to fix it

I get

[image]

I need

[image]

I need `lay` because it defines the starting point of`widget_2`

I need something that `lay` and`widget_2` could dynamically change their size depending on the content

And I need to be able to click on `radio` without tracking his position in space. because if there will be many buttons then write for each

```
        self.x1r1, self.x2r1, self.y1r1, self.y2r1 = ..., ..., ..., ...     
        self.x1r2, self.x2r2, self.y1r2, self.y2r2 = ..., ..., ..., ...
        self.x1r3, self.x2r3, self.y1r3, self.y2r3 = ..., ..., ..., ...
    def onButtonClicked(self, id):
        print(id)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):                                       
        g1 = self.radio.geometry()
        self.x1r1 = g1.x() 
        self.y1r1 = g1.y()
        self.x2r1 = g1.x() + g1.width()
        self.y2r1 = g1.y() + g1.height()


        super().resizeEvent(event)  

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):     
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        if (self.x1r1 < x < self.x2r1) and (self.y1r1 < y < self.y2r1):
            self.radio.click()
```

too energy consuming.

Comment: Well, you're not adding `widget_2` to any layout at all, so it has no way to know when the parent changes its size. Use `lay.addWidget(widget_2)`.

Comment: the `widget_2` should go parallel to the `lay` and is in the free position .And I want to use  `widget_2.move()`

Comment: You either add a widget to a layout and let that layout manage the widget size and position, or you manually set its [`geometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop). You can't use both of them in a transparent/automatic way.

Comment: @musicamante But I use two different widgets with one parent. Why I can’t apply one to one and the second to the second

Comment: please rephrase your previous comment better, as it's not clear.

Comment: @musicamante I will try. There is a main widget now this `Test(QWidget)` And connected to this widget `widget_2` and layout `lay`.There are other widgets inside `lay` they determine the size of `Test(QWidget)`. and  `widget_2` moves freely in `Test(QWidget)` area. But I don’t understand why the `widget_2` does not change its size, because it’s located freely from the layout.

Comment: You're setting a layout manager *ON* `widget_2`, but you're *not* adding that widget *TO* a layout manager. This means that that widget (and all of its contents) are completely unaware of any geometry change on their parent, so you have to set the `widget_2` geometry on your own. There is **no** other solution. On the other hand, this doesn't make much sense: "I need to be able to click on radio without tracking his position in space". Considering your previous questions, I'm afraid you're trying to find a difficult solution for a different and unrelated problem (aka, another XY problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. But this is a Workaround

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget_block = QWidget(self)

        widget_block.setStyleSheet('background:{};'.format('yellow'))

        lay_2 = QVBoxLayout(widget_block)

        lay_2.setSpacing(0)
        lay_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)


        label_1 = QLabel(widget_block)
        label_1.setText("Test - 1")
        label_1.setStyleSheet('background:{};margin:100'.format('red'))
        lay_2.addWidget(label_1)

        self.radio = QRadioButton(widget_block)
        self.radio.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.radio.setStyleSheet('background:{};margin:100'.format('black'))
        lay_2.addWidget(self.radio)



        self.resize(widget_block.sizeHint().width(), widget_block.sizeHint().height())
        widget_2 = QWidget(self)


        widget_2.setStyleSheet('background:{}'.format('brown'))
        widget_2.move(10,10)

        widget_2.raise_()

        lay_3 = QVBoxLayout(widget_2)

        lay_3.setSpacing(0)
        lay_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        label_2 = QLabel(widget_2)
        label_2.setText("Test - 2")
        label_2.setStyleSheet('background:{}'.format('blue'))
        lay_3.addWidget(label_2)

        label_3 = QLabel(widget_2)
        label_3.setText("Test - 3")
        label_3.setStyleSheet('background:{}; padding:10'.format('red'))
        lay_3.addWidget(label_3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```